# How to detect hashed password length?

Tags: php, hash, passwords

I've started learning of password hashing. And I wonder how to detect hashed password length?  Right now I'm experimenting with sha512 and one  of the question is how to get user typed password length? Or is it impossible and I should validate user typed password length (e.g. if it is more than 8 characters) with javascript before sending a password to server? Could anybody explain me or suggest some learning material?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  What length are you trying to get? Why?

Comment: Once a password is hashed there is no way to get any info about it's original form.

Comment: Hashing is one-way. Starting from the hash there is no way of finding out any information about the original string. That's the whole point of hashing algorithms.

Comment: @SLaks User inputed password length. For example, I wanna make sure if the password is at least 8 characters length.

Comment: @user2699508: You need to validate _before_ hashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashing is a [one-way function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/One-WayFunction.html), which results in a string of constant length. (At least, the common ones, including sha-512. I don't know if constant length is guaranteed by the definition of hash.)

If you think about what a hash does, this should be obvious. A hash converts any string into a, say, 32 character string. Of course, not all information about an arbitrarily long string can be stored in a string of finite, predetermined length! Thus, according to the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), there must exist [hash collisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_collisions) -- circumstances in which 2 strings hash to the same value. You can't fit n pigeons into n-1 pigeonholes!

Since we know there are infinite hash collisions, (because there are infinite possible strings), we can prove that at least 2 (really infinite) strings of different lengths will hash to the same value. Thus, since the length could be several (infinite) values from the same hash, you clearly can't get the correct length (or any real identifying information, using a good hash,) of the original string.

For example, the SHA-512 of "a":

`1f40fc92da241694750979ee6cf582f2d5d7d28e18335de05abc54d0560e0f5302860c652bf08d560252aa5e74210546f369fbbbce8c12cfc7957b2652fe9a75`

and of aldfksjhalkdfjh:

`cde67871372c0a5e90ea3ae4b14ca3daa5ccd63f16b1f74181e2ab2d7bad2774a439f84d64d6c58eb77c17b03957ba98b897a14048b93cf18451500fd6f1ac41`

Same length. The whole point of hashing is that it hides the nature of the original password. There's no reason to calculate the hash until you have validated that the password is legal, anyway. So, yes, server side validation is the way to go!

There are a lot of excellent resources out there for good password storing practices. You should take a look at those if you're planning to have a site with user passwords.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to get the *length* of the original *password* by decrypting the hash, because that is the protection of your *password*. You can see yourself at most common websites, when you forget your password and want to retrieve it, you almost always get a random code to change your password to a new one, it isn't possible to just get the password already stored in the database, because it was hashed.

**How storing and checking should be done:**

You should convert a plain password to a hash, the hash will be stored in the database at register in the password field, everytime the user logs in, the plain password will be converted to a hash and checked if it matches the hash in the database. That way the password is already hashed when checking with database.

Comment: Let's talk about registration process. For example user fills registration form and sends it to a server. So first of all, I should validate his inputs and if everything is right, add it to a database?

Comment: @user2699508 please don't add the raw password to the database!

Comment: @rogaos no I mean, if it's valid, when hash, salt it an finally add to a database.

Comment: No you hash the password when the user registers, when the user , tries to login you retrieve the hash from the database and you hash the plain password to a hash and compare them for a match.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get any information about the password after it's been hashed. That's the entire point of doing so. Check your length before hashing **on the server** (not client-side in Javascript) and reject and don't hash the password if it doesn't pass validation.

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, is it secure to send users typed password as a plain string? E.g. During registration, user types "password" and  sends it as a plain text.

Comment: The user has to send it *to you* as plain text. You should never send it *to him* in any form.

Comment: @user2699508 - Yes a password can be sent plaintext to the server. There is no advantage to hash the password before sending, because the hash would act as the password itself. To send the password securely, you will need an encrypted SLL connection.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be sending the credentials over to the server over HTTPS and then hash the password with a salt that you can derived from the user data. The hashed password is then stored in your persistence and whenever the user credentials are presented, you re-create the hash based on the salt and then compare the hash against what you have in persistence.

If the question is regarding password strength, then you can use javascript to actually compute the length of the password as a client side validation itself.

Answer (score 0):

you send it to the server unencrypted when the form submits or the AJAX request executes, then you check the length before you run the

```
$password = $_POST['password'];
$length = strlen($password); 
hash("sha512", $password);
```

Good luck

Answer (score -2):

count($string)

Depending on the hashed password type the lengths are always the same.
md5 is 32 i believe (not sure)

Comment: The user asked of password length before computed hashed not after.